# change the width of the <p:selectOneMenu>

Tags: css, primefaces

I have a slectOnMenu component I am trying to Change the width of slectOnMenu by setting the `width:120% !important;` in the style after overridering `.ui-selectonemenu, ui-selectonemenu-` but I am getting just the Label changed how can I move the trigger too? I want to change the selectOneMenu width like the white area below.

**CSS**

```
              <h:form id="rqScannerForm">
                 <style type="text/css">
                    .ui-selectonemenu{width: 120% !important;} 
                    .ui-selectonemenu-label{width: 120% !important;}
                 </style>
                  <p:selectOneMenu  style="width: 120% !important;}" scrollHeight="150" 
                  value="#{viewEventStatusController.eventStatusId}"  disabled="#{!eventStatusController.isEntityEditable}" autoWidth="false" >
                  <f:selectItems value="#{viewEventStatusController.eventStatusList}" var="eventStatus" itemValue="#{eventStatus.id}" itemLabel="#{eventStatus.objectId}" />
                  </p:selectOneMenu>
              </h:form>
```

**screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.ui-selectonemenu {
    min-width: 50% !important;
}
```

Just be aware that making a width bigger then 100% can mess up your layout. I have never ever used one bigger then 100%!. If you meant pixels use

```
.ui-selectonemenu {
    min-width: 120px !important;
}
```

To be more responsive-save use em instead of px:

```
.ui-selectonemenu {
    min-width: 8em !important;
}
```

Comment: Not the best suggestion (not a very good one in fact). Don't use !important, only use it as a very last resort. Learn about css specificity!

Comment: @Kukeltje Then please provide a better one ;-) I'm very aware of specificity ;-)

Comment: See the duplicate

Comment: @Kukeltje what about Primefaces generated width in inline style attribute after css are loaded? Primefaces itself uses also !important 12 times in the component.css sheet. So never say never ;-) If you still believe in this case you can avoid !important I am very eager to see a better suggestion

Comment: From the duplicate: The !important should _only_ be used in order to override the values hardcoded in HTML element's style attribute from a CSS stylesheet file on (which is in turn also a bad practice, but in some rare cases unfortunately unavoidable).

Comment: @Kukeltje first you say it's not the best suggestion, then you confirm it's the only solution to be used in this case... I don't see where your comments are going. :-) Also not a duplicate because it states 'hardcoded' and not 'Primefaces-javascript-generated' which is still a very important difference. The hardcoded values are upfront known by the user, while the generated only after rendering... For primefaces beginners this should be made undisputedly clear. I hope you understand my point of view :-)

Comment: Nice it works it is possiable to change the heigth too?

Comment: @tree Google is your friend ;-) height is an easy one ;-)

Comment: I have already googled it and I appreciate any help since i have tried to override `.menu .ui-selectonemenu-label {  height: 30px !important; } ` after adding `height: 30px;` to the `selectOneMenu` but it did not work well.

Comment: @tree create a new question and tag me in the comment ;-)

Comment: Ok I found it :)

Comment: I'm not saying it is the only solution. That is quote from the duplicate that states when to use it. And both hardcoded values and values set via javascript end up in the styles attribute. Both have the same 'weight', so no real difference and hence the duplicate is a duplicate even if !important is needed. Primefaces users should know the duplicate at first. Cheers!